# Google Chrome how to manually stop plugins

Tags: google-chrome, adobe-flash

Some blog sites have Abode flash player embedded and automatically play musics when the page is loaded. This is annoying. The music can be stopped by clicking "stop" button in IE/Firefox. I was wondering how to manually stop it in Google Chrome. I know clicking the "stop" button in the flash player certainly works, but find out where the player is located on the page is annoying too. So hopefully there's a way to manually stop it from Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu -> Tools -> Task Manager, then look for `Plug-in: Shockwave Flash`.  Usually the ones that are playing annoying music and/or animation are using more CPU.

Select & click the [End Process] button to restore your sanity!

---

**BUT**, my personal approach is to use the "FlashBlock" chrome extension so that Flash does not run anywhere unless I click the [f] icon on the page.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flashblock/cdngiadmnkhgemkimkhiilgffbjijcie

Comment: What if I have several YouTube pages and the annoying blog page opened, and just want to block flash player on the blog page. Would killing/blocking flash plugin an overkill?

Comment: My apologies, I thought that when Chrome started sandboxing Flash (v21 on Windows, v24 on Mac) it ran one Flash process per tab.  Not true.  Experiments confirm that killing the flash player affects all the browser windows.  Looks like FlashBlock (or Click to play) is your only real option.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite what you're asking, but if you open Chrome's settings and click `Show advanced settings > Content settings > Plug-ins > Click to play`, Flash won't load with the page at all, and you can choose to activate it as you wish. This has the bonus of making advertisement-ridden pages much faster.